# How to access DOM model with JWebBrowser?

Tags: java, dom, jwebbrowser

Is there are any way to access DOM model with JWebBrowser from Dj project http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html ? If no, could you please suggest alternatives that can do that. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the DOM model via JavaScript executed via the method executeJavascriptWithResult of JWebBrowser.